# Proper way to access parent's methods in child class

Tags: php

I have a `ChildClass` that extends to a `ParentClass`. The `ParentClass` has a constructor that takes two arguments `__construct('value2', ParentClass::COMMON)`. HOwever I am trying to call the inherited `newSelect()` method from within the child class. So far it has not been succesfull. How would I call `NewSelect()` from the `ChildClass`? Also is it possible even though the `ParentClass` has a constructor that takes two parameters?

Parent

```
class ParentClass {    

const COMMON = 'common';

protected $db;

protected $common = false;

protected $quotes = array(
'Common' => array('"', '"'),
'Value2' => array('`', '`'),
'Value3' => array('`', '`'),
'Value4' => array('`', '`'),
);

protected $quote_name_prefix;

protected $quote_name_suffix;

   public function __construct($db, $common = null) {
    $this->db = ucfirst(strtolower($db));
    $this->common = ($common === self::COMMON);
    $this->quote_name_prefix = $this->quotes[$this->db][0];
    $this->quote_name_suffix = $this->quotes[$this->db][1];
   }

 public function newSelect() {
    return $this->newInstance('Select');
 }

 protected function newInstance($query) {
    //Some more code,  not relevant to example
 }


}
```

Child

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {    



    public function __construct() {

    }

    // Call the inherited method

    private $_select = Parent::newSelect();

    // Do something with it

}
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors or what happens?

Comment: @u_mulder Yes, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'` or if i create an object with `new` within the child class i get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new'`.

Comment: Syntax errors happen at certain lines, what arer the line exactly and what code is on those lines?

Comment: First of all assigning a property a result of funciton is illegal, so `private $_select = Parent::newSelect();` is the cause of first syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// you can't do this

```
private $_select = Parent::newSelect();
```

// try this

```
private $_select;

public function construct($value, $common)
{
    Parent::__construct($value, $common);
    $this->_select = $this->newSelect();
}
```

// and

```
$obj = new ChildClass('Value2', ParentClass::COMMON); //  ParentClass::COMMON - not sure why you would do this
$select = $obj->newSelect(); // this is being called in constructor, why call it again
```

and to be honest, I don't even know what you're trying to do but everything about it looks wrong too!

Comment: Ok will test this once I get the chance in the next few minutes. Oh I probably didnt make myself clear but disregard the `$obj = new ChildClass()...`